# SUMIFS in python jupyter

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, sumifs

I have this dataframe. This is a transaction of exchange goods. So basically the client can switch into those goods which have the same quality or lower. So for Client 1 on 16/08/2019, 360 B grade goods switch into 180 B and 180 A goods. This needs to be flagged.
I can do this in excel, however, the file is too big and it crashes.

```
 In/Out Client  Quality Date         GoodsAmount
 In     1       A       16/08/2019      180
 In     1       B       16/08/2019      180
 Out    1       B       16/08/2019      360
 In     2       C       14/08/2019      130
 Out    2       B       14/08/2019      45
 Out    2       C       14/08/2019      85
 In     1       B       18/08/2019      80
 In     1       A       18/08/2019      60
 Out    1       A       18/08/2019      140
```

I want to create a new column which will be =GoodsAmount/SUMIFS(GoodsAmount by Client, Quality, In/Out, and Date)

I check on this URL: [Pandas: Adding an excel SUMIF column like =A1/SUMIF(B:B,B1,A:A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053723/pandas-adding-an-excel-sumif-column-like-a1-sumifbb-b1-aa)

And my code is:

```
# df['Percentage']=df.GoodsAmount/(df.groupby(['In/Out','Client','Quality','Date'])['GoodsAmount'].transform('sum'))
```

However, there is an error.

In the end, what I have this table in mind.

```
|        |           | Switch   in         | Switch   Out         |          |
|--------|-----------|:-----------:|:-:|:-:|:------------:|:-:|:-:|----------|
| Client | Date      | A           | B | C | A            | B | C | Flagged? |
| 1      | 16-Aug-19 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 1      | 18-Aug-19 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 2      | 14-Aug-19 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 2      | 20-Sep-19 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 2      | 31-Oct-19 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 3      | 11-Mar-19 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 3      | 13-Feb-20 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
| 3      | 12-Aug-20 |             |   |   |              |   |   |          |
```

Comment: add desired results into table. What value need to by putted below each columns: A,B,C?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot help correct the SUMIFS code, but you don't need using SUMIFS to finish this

pandas has a function [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) that may help you

just like your post

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'In/Out': {0: 'In', 1: 'In', 2: 'Out', 3: 'In', 4: 'Out', 5: 'Out', 6: 'In', 7: 'In', 8: 'Out'}, 'Client': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}, 'Quality': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'B', 5: 'C', 6: 'B', 7: 'A', 8: 'A'}, 'Date': {0: '16/08/2019', 1: '16/08/2019', 2: '16/08/2019', 3: '14/08/2019', 4: '14/08/2019', 5: '14/08/2019', 6: '18/08/2019', 7: '18/08/2019', 8: '18/08/2019'}, 'GoodsAmount': {0: 180, 1: 180, 2: 360, 3: 130, 4: 45, 5: 85, 6: 80, 7: 60, 8: 140}})
```

you should use:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df, values='GoodsAmount', index=['Client','Date'],
                    columns=['In/Out','Quality'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

and this will return
[image]
the args are described by the docs above

Comment: wow, thank you! surprising this is much simple than what I want to do. Thanks alot.