# Python Pivot Table based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I was asking the question in this link [SUMIFS in python jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060574/sumifs-in-python-jupyter/64061285#64061285)

However, I just realized that the solution didn't work because they can switch in and switch out on  different dates. So basically they have to switch out first before they can switch in.

Here is the dataframe (sorted based on the date):

```
+---------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
| Switch In/Out | Client | Quality |   Date    | Amount |
+---------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
| Out           |      1 | B       | 15-Aug-19 |    360 |
| In            |      1 | A       | 16-Aug-19 |    180 |
| In            |      1 | B       | 17-Aug-19 |    180 |
| Out           |      1 | A       | 18-Aug-19 |    140 |
| In            |      1 | B       | 18-Aug-19 |     80 |
| In            |      1 | A       | 19-Aug-19 |     60 |
| Out           |      2 | B       | 14-Aug-19 |     45 |
| Out           |      2 | C       | 15-Aug-20 |     85 |
| In            |      2 | C       | 15-Aug-20 |    130 |
| Out           |      2 | A       | 20-Aug-19 |    100 |
| In            |      2 | A       | 22-Aug-19 |     30 |
| In            |      2 | B       | 23-Aug-19 |     30 |
| In            |      2 | C       | 23-Aug-19 |     40 |
+---------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I would then create a new column and divide them into different transactions.

```
+---------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+------+
| Switch In/Out | Client | Quality |   Date    | Amount | Rows |
+---------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+------+
| Out           |      1 | B       | 15-Aug-19 |    360 |    1 |
| In            |      1 | A       | 16-Aug-19 |    180 |    1 |
| In            |      1 | B       | 17-Aug-19 |    180 |    1 |
| Out           |      1 | A       | 18-Aug-19 |    140 |    2 |
| In            |      1 | B       | 18-Aug-19 |     80 |    2 |
| In            |      1 | A       | 19-Aug-19 |     60 |    2 |
| Out           |      2 | B       | 14-Aug-19 |     45 |    3 |
| Out           |      2 | C       | 15-Aug-20 |     85 |    3 |
| In            |      2 | C       | 15-Aug-20 |    130 |    3 |
| Out           |      2 | A       | 20-Aug-19 |    100 |    4 |
| In            |      2 | A       | 22-Aug-19 |     30 |    4 |
| In            |      2 | B       | 23-Aug-19 |     30 |    4 |
| In            |      2 | C       | 23-Aug-19 |     40 |    4 |
+---------------+--------+---------+-----------+--------+------+
```

With this, I can apply the pivot formula and take it from there.
However, how do I do this in python? In excel, I can just use multiple SUMIFS and compare in and out. However, this is not possible in python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to iterate and apply a check (function) over each element being the result a new column, so: map.

Using `df.index.map` we get the index for each item to pass as a argument, so we can play with the values, get and compare. In your case your aim is to identify the change to "Out" keeping a counter.

```py
import pandas as pd
switchInOut = ["Out", "In", "In", "Out", "In", "In", 
               "Out", "Out", "In", "Out", "In", "In", "In"]
df = pd.DataFrame(switchInOut, columns=['Switch In/Out'])
counter = 1

def changeToOut(i):
    global counter
    if df["Switch In/Out"].get(i) == "Out" and df["Switch In/Out"].get(i-1) == "In":
        counter += 1
    return counter

rows = df.index.map(changeToOut)
df["Rows"] = rows
df
```

Result:

```
+----+-----------------+--------+
|    | Switch In/Out   |   Rows |
|----+-----------------+--------|
|  0 | Out             |      1 |
|  1 | In              |      1 |
|  2 | In              |      1 |
|  3 | Out             |      2 |
|  4 | In              |      2 |
|  5 | In              |      2 |
|  6 | Out             |      3 |
|  7 | Out             |      3 |
|  8 | In              |      3 |
|  9 | Out             |      4 |
| 10 | In              |      4 |
| 11 | In              |      4 |
| 12 | In              |      4 |
+----+-----------------+--------+
```